# Solving for a difference equation for a time series variable

Tags: time-series, lags

I am trying to solve for the values of a variable $u_t$. $u_t$ is defined as:

$(1-L-L^2)u_t = \epsilon_t$

where $L$ is the lag operator and $t=1,...,n$. $\epsilon_t$ is a random variable (normal[0,1]) that can be generated. Using the values of $\epsilon_t$, how can I solve for $u_t$.

Comment: Is this a question from a course or textbook? If so, please add the `[self-study]`
tag & read its [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: Hey Gung- this is a general form of a problem I'm facing in a project, not from a specific textbook or course.

Comment: It's not stationary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewriting your equation using the properties of $L$ we have $$u_t=u_{t-1}+u_{t-2}+\epsilon_t$$

This is a second order difference equation and pinning a solution down for it requires two conditions (read intializations). For example set $u_0=u_{-1}=0$ then \begin{align}
u_1&=\epsilon_1\\
u_2&=\epsilon_1+\epsilon_2\\
u_3&=2\epsilon_1+\epsilon_2+\epsilon_3\\
u_4&=3\epsilon_1+2\epsilon_2+\epsilon_3+\epsilon_4\\
...
\end{align}